# maven-release-plugin deploying SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, git, maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a Maven project and now want to release it with the maven-release-plugin. Unfortunately after executing `mvn release:prepare` the git tag contains the old version number (1.0-SNAPSHOT) and when deploying to artifactory the SNAPSHOT version is used instead of the desired release version.

I already found [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-812) bug, but all suggested solutions are not working for me.

I'm using:

- Apache Maven 3.3.9
- git version 2.7.0 (German)

I already tried several versions of the release plugin (2.4, 2.5.3, 2.5.1) but none woked. 
Does anyone have a fix for that problem?

***EDIT1:*** The current pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
  <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <!-- [...] -->

  <scm>
    <url>http://url/to/gitlab</url>
    <connection>scm:git:git@gitlab:group/repo.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@gitlab:group/repo.git</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
  </scm>

  <!-- [...] -->

  <distributionManagement>
    <!-- [...] -->
  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you show the pom file? And what it mean `git tag contains the old version number`?

Comment: When I look at the pom in the git tag (by checking out or in gitlab) it still has the `<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>`

Comment: Have you pinned the maven-release-plugin version in your pom file? Via pluginManagement ?

Comment: No, I specified the version in the <build><plugins> section ([example](http://pastebin.com/MgXQ5v9u))

Comment: Can you show the full log output during the run...and failing release procedure...BTW: Have you checked your local git repo or checked also the remote repository ? Does the `mvn release:prepare ..` fail or do you use `mvn release:prepare release:perform`?

Comment: It does not fail and there are no errors. It creates the tag, and deploys the artifact, but in version 1.0-SNAPSHOT instead of 1.0. `mvn release:prepare` asks me for the version, but does not use it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with maven-release-plugin 2.5.3 and git 2.8.2 . I try different versions of maven-release-plugin and even forcing maven-svm-provider-git to the last version. Looks related to this issue : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-812